# how to display response object of Node.js to plane html table format

Tags: html, node.js

```
userRouter.get('/allProducts',function(req,res){
    console.log("inside all products")
    productModel.find({},function(err,productList){
        if(err){

            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send(productList);
        }
```

The above response object  gives products output as below in html

```
  [{"productName":"treseme","productType":"shampoo","features":"low 
  sulphite","price":185,"_id":"5ae09b926b6ad826bc1ce42e","__v":0}, 
  {"productName":"treseme","productType":"shampoo","features":"low 
  sulphite","price":185,"_id":"5ae09c0a6b6ad826bc1ce42f","__v":0}, 
  {"productName":"pantene","productType":"shampoo","features":"low 
  sulphite","price":95,"_id":"5ae10e9a1c31142a5c5258b8","__v":0}]
```

i would like to display the above object as table in the HTML file, what 
  is the produre in node.js to html direct viewing as table.

i would like to display it in simple HTML table format.please help me out 
 of this situation. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write your HTML directly in the response:

```
userRouter.get('/allProducts',function(req,res){

    console.log("inside all products")

    productModel.find({},function(err,productList){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);

        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        productList.forEach( (product) => {
            // Write your HTML here
            res.write('<span>' + product.productName + '</span><br/>');
        });
        res.end();
    });

});
```